# Animated show where the main character travels to another world. His father had apparently also been there

Tags: story-identification, tv, isekai, animated-series

Watched it on Cartoon Network in 2007-2010. A boy travels to another world. A magical one. I think his father went there before and saved it. This boy also saves it. He is not necessarily a boy. A teenager/young adult.

I do not remember well but I remember it more being a Western production than an anime if I remember its animation style correctly. However, open to all identifications

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What did the boy look like? Did he travel to the other world alone? Can you tell us anything about any other characters in the show, such as allies or antagonists?

Comment: sorry. too little to remember then. magic was involved in there if I could guess (no idea to how much degree). His mom was maybe in the picture in the human realm but thats a stretch (this could be a mix of memory from my side)

Comment: Hmm... nothing that matches on https://www.imdb.com/list/ls063964465/?sort=release_date,desc&st_dt=&mode=detail&page=1 that I can see. Was this Cartoon Network in the United States?

Comment: it was the UK
I feel very strongly about seeing it on Cartoon Network. but I could be wrong.
the animation style wasnt dumbed down as most cartoon shows are

Comment: Were there crystals and summoned creatures?  (If so, maybe it was his _grand_father who had been there before?)

Comment: If you are referring to Huntik, then probably not. The animated style was different

Comment: Actually I was thinking of [*Magi-Nation*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1001475/).  The style is a bit different.

Comment: I can definitely say I have seen Magi-nation. Thanks. This seems like the one. Albeit. I feel I have seen another show similar to the info above with better animation. But this satisfies my curiosity. Thanks a ton mate. If you know another show with above features and better animation do tell. A childs memory can be a weird thing haha

Comment: Sounded like Slugterra (notionally scientific but lots of magic-type elements) but that didn't come out until 2012

Comment: Wild guess but is it Idaten Jump? His father got stuck there after repairing Imperial X and fell into the clutches of evil.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the discussion in the comments above, it seems likely this is [*Magi-Nation*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1001475/).

The protagonist, Tony Jones, is running when he is summoned to the Moonlands to save them from Agram and his Shadow Magi.  Tony's Dream Creature is Furok, who had also been the Dream Creature of Tony's grandfather Spencer Jones when Spencer had previously come to help the Moonlands. (Though only Tony is the Final Dreamer who can conclusively defeat Agram.)